# How to solve this hsl to rgb vise versa color conversion error in python?

Tags: python-3.x

yesterday I tried to made a simple library to convert HSL to RGB color space and vise-versa program in python.
but when I tried to run everything seems normal but sometimes on some input they miss by the one digit difference.
here is my code and result.

```
import re

# helper hsl functions

hslString=r'^hsl\((\d+)\,(\d+)%\,(\d+)%\)$'
hslaString=r'^hsla\((\d+)\,(\d+)%\,(\d+)%\,(0?\.?\d+)\)$'
wrongHslaString=r'^hsl\((\d+)\,(\d+)%\,(\d+)%\,(0?\.?\d+)\)$'
wrongHslString=r'^hsla\((\d+)\,(\d+)%\,(\d+)%\)$'
def hasall(obj,*args):
    return False if False in [True if i in obj else False for i in args] else True
def ishsl(*hsl):
    rl=len(hsl)
    if rl==1:
        arg=hsl[0]
        if isinstance(arg,dict):
            a=hasall(arg,'h','s','l','a') or hasall(arg,'h','s','l')
            return [*arg.values()] if a else False
        elif isinstance(arg,str):
            values=re.findall(hslaString,arg) or re.findall(hslString,arg) or re.findall(wrongHslaString,arg) or re.findall(wrongHslString,arg)
            return [float(v) for v in values[0]] if values else False
        elif isinstance(arg,(list,tuple)):
            return [*arg] if len(arg) in [3,4] else False
    elif rl in [3,4]:
        return [*hsl]
    return False
def typehsl(*hsl):
    check=ishsl(*hsl)
    if check:
        return 'hsla' if len(check)==4 else 'hsl'
    else:
        return False


# helper rgb functions

rgbString=r'^rgb\(\s*?(\-?\d+)\s*?\,\s*?(\-?\d+)\s*?\,\s*?(\-?\d+)\s*?\)$'
rgbaString=r'^rgba\(\s*(\-?\d+)\s*\,\s*(\-?\d+)\s*\,\s*(\-?\d+)\s*\,(\-?0?\.?\d+)\)$'
wrongRgbaString=r'^rgba\(\s*(\-?\d+)\s*\,\s*(\-?\d+)\s*\,\s*(\-?\d+)\)$'
wrongRgbString=r'^rgb\(\s*(\-?\d+)\s*\,\s*(\-?\d+)\s*\,\s*(\-?\d+)\s*\,(\-?0?\.?\d+)\)$'
# sampleRgbString='rgb(150,150,252)'
# compiled=re.compile(rgbString).findall(sampleRgbString)
def hasall(obj,*args):
    """check if given object has all property name or not"""
    value=False
    for i in args:
        if obj.get(i):
            value=True
        else:
            value=False
    return value
def getinorder(obj,*args):
    all=hasall(obj,*args)
    vals=[]
    if all:
        for i in args:
            vals.append(obj.get(i))
    return vals
def isrgb(*rgb):
    rl=len(rgb)
    if rl==1:
        arg=rgb[0]
        if isinstance(arg,dict):
            a=hasall(arg,'r','g','b','a') or hasall(arg,'r','g','b')
            values = getinorder(arg,'r','g','b','a') or getinorder(arg,'r','g','b') 
            return [int(v) for v in values] if a else False
        elif isinstance(arg,str):
            values=re.findall(rgbaString,arg) or re.findall(rgbString,arg) or re.findall(wrongRgbaString,arg) or re.findall(wrongRgbString,arg)
            return [int(v) for v in values[0]] if values else False
        elif isinstance(arg,(list,tuple)):
            return [*arg] if  len(arg) in [3,4] else False
    elif rl in [3,4]:
        return [*rgb]
    return False
def typergb(*rgb):
    check=isrgb(*rgb)
    if check:
        rl=len(check)
        return 'rgba' if rl==4 else 'rgb' if rl==3 else False

def RGB2HSL(*rgb):
    check=isrgb(*rgb)
    if check:
        h=s=l=0
        tr=typergb(check)
        A=float(check.pop()) if tr=='rgba' else False
        check=[0 if v<0 else 255 if v>255 else v for v in check]
        r,g,b=[int(v)/255 for v in check]
        maxi,mini=max(r,g,b),min(r,g,b)
        l=(maxi+mini)/2
        if maxi==mini:
            h=s=0
            return [h,s,l,A] if tr=='rgba' else [h,s,l]
        else:
            s=(maxi-mini)/(1-abs(2*l-1))
        if maxi==r:
            h=((g-b)/(maxi-mini))%6
        if maxi==g:
            h=(b-r)/(maxi-mini)+2
        if maxi==b:
            h=(r-g)/(maxi-mini)+4
        h=cr(h*60)
        return [h,s,l,A] if tr=='rgba' else [h,s,l]
    else:return False

def cr(n):
    from math import ceil,floor
    return floor(n) if (n-floor(n))<0.5 else ceil(n)

def HSL2RGB(*hsl):
    check=ishsl(*hsl)
    if check:
        r=g=b=0
        tl=typehsl(check)
        A=float(check.pop()) if len(check)==4 else False
        h,s,l=[v for v in check]
        s,l=s if s<=1 else s/100,l if l<=1 else l/100
        c=(1-abs((2*l)-1))*s
        x=c*(1-abs((h/60)%2-1))
        m=l-(c/2)
        if h>=0 and h<60:
            r,g,b=c,x,0
        elif h>=60 and  h<120:
            r,g,b=x,c,0
        elif h>=120 and  h<180:
            r,g,b=0,c,x
        elif h>=180 and  h<240:
            r,g,b=0,x,c
        elif h>=240 and  h<300:
            r,g,b=x,0,c
        elif h>=300 and  h<360:
            r,g,b=c,0,x
        R,G,B=(r+m)*255,(g+m)*255,(b+m)*255
        R,G,B=[cr(v) for v in [R,G,B]]
        return [R,G,B,A] if tl=='hsla' else [R,G,B]
print(HSL2RGB(RGB2HSL(6,50,90)))
```

[image]

I think the result should be **[6,50,90]** but it print **[6,49,90]**. Why? how can I solve this?